# Insert into SQLite with variables using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, sqlite, firefox-addon

I am developing an extension for Firefox and I have created SQLite DB. When inserting values into the table I get an error message:

> Error: Permission denied for http://en.wikipedia.org to call method
>   UnnamedClass.toString on <>.

The string values to be inserted are stored in a variable.

```
var book = "Harry Potter";
var myInsertQuery = 'INSERT INTO mybooks_tbl(title) VALUES('+ book + ');';
```

How do we insert data into the table as variables and not as strings?

Comment: That error message is quite unlikely to have anything to do with your problem.. Care to post more of the code?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite follows the ANSI standard for [string literals](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row

so:

```
function sqlstr(s) {
    return "'"+s.replace(/'/g, "''")+"'";
}

var query= 'INSERT INTO books(title) VALUES('+sqlstr(book)+');';
```

You must remember to escape all string literals like this, or you will have made a client-side SQL-injection hole.

Comment: Really, you shouldn't do the escaping yourself, however.  You should use the binding functions that are available and let the engine handle it for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Storage#Binding_Parameters

Comment: Thanks and i found a way around it by binding the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is error in the string only
  var query= 'INSERT INTO books(title) VALUES('+sqlstr(book)+');';

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CLASS_LIST ("class_title","") VALUES("+v.classTitle+")');

Answer (score 0):

For **sqlite3**:

After some research, I found a simple way to not worry about assembling the string of a query. You've just to add parameters with colon ahead.

```js
let myObj = {
    paramOne: "First value",
    paramTwo: "Second value",
};
let sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(:paramOne, :paramTwo);';

# Run command and variable will be replaces
db.run(sqlQuery, [myObj.paramOne, myObj.paramTwo], ...)
```